# Variable inside window.confirm

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code:

```
use_result = window.confirm("You have 1 registration credits. Do you wish to use a registration credit for this player?");
```

The digit `1` there is not dynamic, it is manually assigned. What I want is that I will have a variable placed instead of the digit `1`, such that it's value is dynamic. Would that be possible? Thanks.

Comment: Just append it to the string.  `You have " + x + " registration credits."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; the easiest would use string concatenation:

```
use_result = window.confirm("You have " + n + " registration credits. Do you wish to use a registration credit for this player?");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace that static value with a variable -

```
var numberOfRegistrations = 1;
use_result = window.confirm("You have "+ numberOfRegistrations +" registration credits. Do you wish to use a registration credit for this player?");
```

The final string that is displayed in the confirm dialog will be a concatenation of the surrounding strings and your predefined dynamic variable.

#### [Here is a very simple jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fqxhK/)

---

In the same way that when you add numeric values together you will get the sum of those values, with strings, using the `+` operator will simple combine the two strings.

```
var firstWord = "Stack";
var secondWord = "Overflow";

alert(firstWord + seconfWord); // This will alert the string - "StackOverflow";
```

You can combine as many strings as you want together to create a final string -

```
alert('Hello' + ' ' + 'World'); // This will alert the string - "Hello World"
```

Note in the last example I am joining 3 strings.

- `Hello`
- A blank space
- `World`

Answer (score 1):

use string concatenation with the + operator.

```
var a = /*... */;
use_result = window.confirm("You have "+ a +" registration credits. Do you wish to use a registration credit for this player?");
```